# Java & Redis - multiple instances of jedis.2.0.0.jar

Tags: java, redis

My current Java programm is making some insertions in Redis and I see with htop about 15 instances of jedis.2.0.0.jar ...

Any ideas why ??? Thanks

Here is part of my code :

```
private Jedis jedis;

 try {
     jedis = new Jedis(REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT); }
 catch (Exception e) {
     System.err.println("Can't connect to Redis");
     return false;
 }

 jedis.hset(...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `htop` utility shows userland threads by default, so what you're seeing is likely threads started by the Jedis library.

You can configure `htop` to either not show threads:

`F2` > `Display Options` > `Hide userland threads`

Or show them in a tree view under the process:

`F2` > `Display Options` > `Tree View`

The tree view is quite a bit clearer than the default view.

Comment: Is it normal that the Jedis libray launch 15 threads ?? My current process is sequential

Comment: The threads might not come only from Jedis, you're likely seeing the standard threads that come along a running JVM. You can see what threads your process has by running `jstack <pid>`.